# why component is not display in react?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-router, react-dom, react-leaflet

I am trying to use `leaflet` in react ..I take reference of this module 
https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet
but it not show map why ?

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/pTpPxhEFqouMrLTrKUFq?p=preview

// Code goes here

```
const { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } = ReactLeaflet;
class A extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 13,
    };
  }
  render(){
    return (
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
    return (

      <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
      <label>cccc</label>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>
            <span>A pretty CSS3 popup. <br/> Easily customizable.</span>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </Map>
    );
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<A/>,document.getElementById('example'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two return statements in your `render`.

`render` should only return the components once.

```
render(){
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
    return (

      <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
      <label>cccc</label>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>
            <span>A pretty CSS3 popup. <br/> Easily customizable.</span>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </Map>
    );
  }
```

Multiple items:

```
{this.state.items.map(item => (
    <Marker position={[item.lat, item.lng]}>
        <Popup>
            <span>A pretty CSS3 popup. <br/> Easily customizable.</span>
        </Popup>
     </Marker

 )}
```

Comment: yup ..!!! i got the solution ..could you please tell me how to add 2 or 3 markers ?

Comment: see this https://plnkr.co/edit/pTpPxhEFqouMrLTrKUFq?p=preview ..in states I have 2 or 3 items how to show icon ?

Comment: @user944513 check the console errors... This plunkr doesn't include script.jsx it includes script.js in the html. This isn't a code error.